# Does spring creates a new object for autowired fields?

Tags: java, spring

I have some scheduler tasks that triggers UserInfoServiceExecutor, AdminInfoServiceExecutor services for every 1 hour(both services starting at the same time).

The problem is these services using LoggerService and LoggerService search method nearly takes 5 minutes to complete(I mean while loop). Since to search userInfo logs you need to login with some user account and to get Admin logs you need to login with some admin account(it means different sessionTokens will return),

Does AdminInfoServiceExecutor override UserInfoServiceExecutor sessionToken when it starts after it?

```
@Service
public class UserInfoServiceExecutor {
    @Autowired
    private LoggerService loggerService;

    public void saveUserInfos(){
        loggerService.loginAndSearch("userInfo");
    }

}

@Service
public class AdminInfoServiceExecutor {
    @Autowired
    private LoggerService loggerService;

    public void saveAdminInfos(){
        loggerService.loginAndSearch("adminInfo");
    }

}

@Service
public class LoggerService{

    private String sessionToken;

    public String loginAndSearch(String key){

        if(key.equals("userInfo"))
           sessionToken = login(user);

        if(key.equals("adminInfo"))
           sessionToken = login(admin);

        search(key);

    }

    public String search(String keyword){
        while(hasMoreResults){
            getResults(keyword, sessionToken);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I am using default Spring scope.(Singleton)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is primarily on the Scope of your **LoggerService** bean, as far as the spring container is concerned, it deals with the scope with how you declare at the time of defining the bean,Spring's default scope is Singleton.

So as you have not mentioned as Scope it will be managed as **Singleton** scope

As you have `sessionToken` as a class member there is every chance of it getting overridden, you might have to deal with synchronization here.

> Note: Synchronized block or Synchronized method only works in the
>   purview of single JVM, in case you deploy your code/application in
>   clustered envioronment in different JVMs this synchronization approach
>   will not work.

Comment: Yes I am using Singleton scope. So does AdminInfoServiceExecutor override UserInfoServiceExecutor sessionToken when it starts after it?

Answer (score 1):

With @Autoired Spring inject a reference of a spring bean. Now if the scope of the jijected bean is Singleton(default behaviour) you will get the same instance in every @Autowired dependency and in all request your service will see the same bean. If your spring bean is configured as Prototype scope in every @Autowired injection tyou will have a new instance of the Spring bean injected but even in this case in every method invocation the bean will be the same. Said that since in your case you need of a statefull bean and not a stateless bean pheraps will be better of use a "domain object" and not a spring bean. I want say that you could be use a clssical pojo annotated with @Configurable and create a new object in every request and use a new object for your propouse. With @Configurable on the cofigurable object and @EnableAspectJAutoProxy @EnableSpringConfigured @EnableLoadTimeWeaving in your configuraion

I hope that it can help you

edit:

I have a my own opensource project PhoneBoock(https://github.com/mrFlick72/phonebook/tree/master/phonebook-java-config) and in it I had a similar problem. I had a builder of PhoneBookUser, the my user had the passowrd encripted with a spring security PasswordEncoder. At the start I had a singleton bean that build the PhoneBookUser PhoneBookUserBuilder but unfortunally being a singleton if two user create a new entity in the sing-up process I had a interleeving ov interaction that may corrupt the data. For solve this problem I refactor my code with a

@Configurable
public class PhoneBookUserBuilder

with @Configurable I can create a new object with new operator and benefit of DI of spring for inject the PasswordEncoder. Tis approach solved my problem. I can suggest of think about it probably can help you.

Comment: If I change my sessionToken to local variable Does it solve the problem?

Comment: I consider of no but I edit my answare with a my experience wit a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will in this case, because you will have one instance of the LoggerService bean. Usually you don't have stateful services, so convert the sessionToken field to a local variable, if you don't want to share that state between your other Spring beans.